# Cannot compare passwords in database

Tags: php, html, redbean

I have a database which contains a user "admin" with password "admin". In `db.php`, I connected RedBeaNPHP. `DB : id,user,password,authority`. But I can't compare passwords. What's going wrong?

```
if( empty( $errors)) 
    {
        $user = R::find( 'users', 'login = ?' , array($data['login']) );
        if($user) 
            {
                $password_db = R::find( 'users', 'password = ?' , 
                                         array($data['password']) );
                if( $password_db) 
                    {
                        echo 5555;
                    }   
            } else 
            {
                echo 'Wrong password';
            }
```

HTML code here :

```
<div id="login">
    <h1>Auth</h1>
    <form name='form-login' method="post">
        <span class="fontawesome-user"></span>
        <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username">
        <span class="fontawesome-lock"></span>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        <input type="submit" value="Login" name="do_login">
    </form>
```

Comment: try use `trim()` on `$data['password']` it removes spaces from string

Comment: What specifically goes wrong? Do you get the "Wrong password" message? Have you done any troubleshooting? Do you get any error messages? What are the values of `$data`, `$user`, `$password_db`?

Comment: Also, I'm not familiar with RedBeanPHP, but I'm not following the logic of your code. It looks like you find a user with a particular username and then perform a separate query to find a user with a particular password, but never a particular username/password pair. If the user isn't found, it says "Wrong password". If the password isn't found, nothing happens. Are you aiming to authenticate a username/password pair?

Comment: @ArtemIlchenko That is bad advice.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton bad practice store passwords as is:)

Comment: @ArtemIlchenko That's incorrect. You do not want to alter a users inputted password, it can cause people to not be able to log in, and causes necessary code. The best practice would be to hash the password exactly as entered, and store the hashed password.

Answer (score 0):

I see the issue is with finding user by login, you are passing invalid data there. Considering $data will have post data.

Repalce

```
$user = R::find( 'users', 'login = ?' , array($data['login']) );
// $data['login'] is not defined.
```

with

```
$user = R::find( 'users', 'login = ?' , array($data['user']) );
```

Comment: That seems like a likely solution, under the reasonable assumption that `$data` contains the posted data.

Answer (score 0):

If you read RedBean documentation ( https://redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/finding )  you will see that "find" returns an Array and, a empty Array if there is no results.
For login purpose I use FindOne the returns only the first row or null.
Another tip, do not be economic at code when you are talking about login.
Do any kind of comparison you can and do not forget about code and SQL injection.